# How correctly produce JSON by RESTful web service?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am writing a web service the first time. I created a RESTful web service based on [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net). And I want to **produce JSON**. What do I need to do to generate the correct JSON type of my web service?

Here's one of my methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/friends")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getFriends() {
    return "{'friends': ['Michael', 'Tom', 'Daniel', 'John', 'Nick']}";
}
```

Is it sufficient that I simply point out annotation `@Produces("application/json")` for my method? Then this method may return any type of object? Or only String? Do I need additional processing or transformation of these objects?

Please help me as a beginner to deal with these issues. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can annotate your bean with jaxb annotations.

```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class MyJaxbBean {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public MyJaxbBean() {} // JAXB needs this

    public MyJaxbBean(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }
  }
```

and then your method would look like this:

```
   @GET @Produces("application/json")
   public MyJaxbBean getMyBean() {
      return new MyJaxbBean("Agamemnon", 32);
   }
```

There is a chapter in the latest documentation that deals with this:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the no-param constructor part. That was important !

Answer (score 5):

You could use a package like org.json http://www.json.org/java/

Because you will need to use JSONObjects more often.

There you can easily create JSONObjects and put some values in it:

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    array.put("1");
    array.put("2");
    json.put("friends", array);

    System.out.println(json.toString(2));


    {"friends": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]}
```

**edit** This has the advantage that you can build your responses in different layers and return them as an object

Answer (score 4):

```
@GET
@Path("/friends")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getFriends() {

    // here you can return any bean also it will automatically convert into json 
    return "{'friends': ['Michael', 'Tom', 'Daniel', 'John', 'Nick']}";
}
```

Comment: How does `@Produces("application/json")` differ from `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing. `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` is a constant whose value is equal to `application/json`. Using a constant is less error-prone so a better choice

Answer (score 1):

```
@POST
@Path ("Employee")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONObject postEmployee(JSONObject jsonObject)throws Exception{
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

Comment: Isn't this a Spring annotation?
I don't think this is valid.

Comment: The OP is pretty clear: _"I created a RESTful web service based on **Jersey**."_ The `@GetMapping` annotation is not part of the Jersey API. It's a Spring MVC annotation.