# Simple RESTful client using Jquery error

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, restful-url

I have problem in callback function in jquery.

lets start from the beginning.  My restful web service url is this

```
http://localhost :35055/new/webresources/generic/1
```

and it will return

> {'name':'get', 'age':58}

and my jquery to interact with this web service is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/webresources/generic/1',
        type: 'GET',
        data: ' ',
        success: function() {
            alert('PUT completed');
        }
    });
});
```

which is linked in the jsp page

```
http://localhost:35055/new/tool.jsp
```

there is no alert message.  Please suggest me a way and also debug this code please.

this is the restful webservice

```
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getJson( @PathParam("venki") int empno ) {
        if(empno==1)
        {
      return "{'name':'get', 'age':'58' }";
        }
        return "{'name':'error', 'age':'58' }";
        }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you configured your service to expect a PUT?

Comment: F12 in chrome, and read the doc to know all the options available !!!

Comment: @keune hi, i tried both...not working...the webservice in get method..even it works for normal form posting....but, not using jquery...

Comment: The json response body is not legal JSON. use **double quote** please.

Comment: @shawnzhu bro...i updated the coding..see, if i change double quote, then it shows errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retry by correcting `url` setting value to `'/new/webresources/generic/1'` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/new/webresources/generic/1', 
  success: function() { alert('PUT completed'); }
});
```

According to your updated Java code of web service implementation, you should refer to answer of [How correctly produce JSON by RESTful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594945/how-correctly-produce-json-by-restful-web-service) to find the correct java code.

Comment: did you see any network traffic under network tab of development tool on chrome or firefox?

Comment: network traffic??? no, i didn't do it bro..actually, what is the use of this in this problem..

Comment: settings like `type` or `data` can be ignored if you do want to perform action **GET**.

Comment: you can paste the javascript code into _Console_ tab of dev tool of chrome, and it should work.

Comment: error code 200, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' do u have any idea bro

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the error through the `error` property of the $.ajax call if you aren't familiar with using Fiddler or the built in browser tools to inspect network traffic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/new/webresources/generic/1',
        type: 'GET',
        data: ' ',
        success: function() {
            alert('PUT completed');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much...it returns some error...its says....200,  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Comment: You most likely need to look at the JSON you're sending back from the service to make sure it's well formed.

Comment: thank you so much @Scott for the help.  this is the coding is very useful for me to find the exact error.