# RESTful web service not producing or consuming JSON

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have a project where I use RESTful web service on the server side to get and post data. It works fine if I specify the MediaType as XML (in @Consumes and @Produces, but it doesn't when it comes to JSON.
Here is an example of a method

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Product find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}
```

When I try to call the service it throws the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
```

However, I tried to do what's explained in the answer of this question [how correctly produce json by restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594945/how-correctly-produce-json-by-restful-web-service), but it changed nothing.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json

Comment: change return type to `Response`

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169) in Eclipse Link.  I think you may need to update to EclipseLink 2.6.1 and Jersey 2.19 or later see also [this link](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2888).  Otherwise you may be missing a dependency of org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper, since that class exists on your classpath but gets an exception trying to load into the JVM.

Comment: When I try to add Jersey library, EntityManager.createCriteriaQuery becomes unknown. I found the reason is that this library contains persistence.xml but I have no idea what to do in order to make my project work along with Jersey.

Comment: I see that it is Jersey and Hibernate incompatibility problem.  But before You put the new jar, you must have had a Jersey jar of some type?  Cant you just update that?

Answer (score 1):

You need download this file

https://mega.nz/#!Ck0lVSRA!_KIjTl_8scQrak7jNTBepv3oqSKgeYsAVqjlvAarTbU

and replace in the next path:

C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules

after open and close the IDE in my case I use Netbeans, test the RESTful.

Comment: Just tried the solution mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json which describes the necessary steps to have the updated jar mentioned in @Victor Jimenez answer. Works like a charm.