# Java ee returns 500 error when returning boolean

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara

I have a java ee application that uses jax-rs. But when i return a boolean in a call that returns json, it gives a 500 error.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public boolean test() {
        return true;
    }
```

The above code will give this generic error message: `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

If i remove the `@Produces("application/json")` it does work but returns 'text/plain'.

Comment: boolean is not a json actually. can you try with map like {"value":true}?

Comment: @OP: you need this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13595212/767881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON consists of `key:value` pairs. So you cannot return a simple boolean, because what should be the name of the corresponding key ?

So either return a `Map<String, Boolean>` or a `boolean[]`

Comment: I still got a 500 when i tried to return a map or a boolean[] but i made a custom class to return the value.Which worked.Thanks!

Comment: I also had to add the `jersey-media-json-jackson` depency to make it work with my custom class.